# Tkinter RadioButton printing previous result in the list box

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter

I am fairly new to Python. I have a simple program that has 3 products, 3 milk options and 3 sizes and an add button, all as radio buttons. The user selects the product, the size, the milk and presses add. The radio-button has values associated to them, e.g. my cappuccino button has value="cappuccino" and my small button has value="small". Upon adding, the values are written to a database and the databases contents are updated to a list-box tkinter widget; so it looks like an order.

My problem is that if i select a certain product, size, and milk type, it writes these details to the database and prints to the list-box, but if select a completely different order it may and add it, it'll write the previous order a couple times to the database as i press add, and then it'll write the correct order.

Any way to fix this so each order is printed as it is. Could it possibly be to the variables storing the previous values. Please can someone provide a solution.

The code below is not everything but gives you a jist of the structure.

```
def view_command():
     self.orderList.delete(0,END) #listbox on screen 2
     for row in backend.view():
         self.orderList.insert(END,row)


def addItem():
    view_command()
    choice = v.get()
    size = s.get()
    milkOptions = m.get()

    backend.customerOrders(choice,size,milkOptions)

self.orderList = tk.Listbox(self,width=112)
self.orderList.place(x=0,y=680)
#Scrollbar for Order Listbox
self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
self.scrollbar.place(x=700,y=685)
#Scroll bar to list box configure
self.orderList.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
self.scrollbar.config(command=self.orderList.yview)



#Americano Button
self.americanoImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/HotDrinks/americanoResized.png")
#self.americanoButton = tk.Radiobutton(self,image=self.americanoImage, command=lambda: product("Americano"),variable=v)
self.americanoButton = tk.Radiobutton(self,image=self.americanoImage,variable=v, value="Americano")

#Cappucino Button
self.cappucinoImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/HotDrinks/cappucinoResized.png")
#self.cappucinoButton = tk.Radiobutton(self,image=self.cappucinoImage, command=lambda: product("Cappucino"),variable=v)
self.cappucinoButton = tk.Radiobutton(self,image=self.cappucinoImage,variable=v, value="Cappucino")

#Espresso Button
self.espressoImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/HotDrinks/espressoResized.png")
#self.espressoButton = tk.Radiobutton(self,image=self.espressoImage, command=lambda: product("Cappucino"),variable=v)
 self.espressoButton = tk.Radiobutton(self,image=self.espressoImage,variable=v, value="Espresso")

#Add button
self.addImage = PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/Function/addResized.png")
self.addButton = Button(self,image=self.addImage,command=addItem)
self.addButton.place(y=550,x=440)

#Small button
self.smallImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/Function/smallResized.png")
self.smallButton = tk.Radiobutton(self,image=self.smallImage,
                                     variable=s, value="Small")
self.smallButton.place(y=550,x=0)
#Medium Button
self.mediumImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/Function/medium_Resized.png")
 self.mediumButton = tk.Radiobutton(self,image=self.mediumImage,
                                      variable=s, value="Medium")
self.mediumButton.place(y=550,x=140)
#Large button
self.largeImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/Function/largeResized.png")
self.largeButton = tk.Radiobutton(self,image=self.largeImage,
                                     variable=s, value="Large")
self.largeButton.place(y=550,x=290)

#ALL MILK OPTION BUTTONS
#Soya Milk Button
self.soyaMilkImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/MilkOptions/soyaMilkResized.png")
self.soyaMilkButton = tk.Radiobutton(self, image=self.soyaMilkImage,variable=m, value="Soya")
#Cocounut Milk Button
self.coconutMilkImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/MilkOptions/coconutMilkResized.png")
self.coconutMilkButton = tk.Radiobutton(self, image=self.coconutMilkImage,variable=m, value="Coconut")
#Whole Milk
self.wholeMilkImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/MilkOptions/wholeMilkResized.png")
self.wholeMilkButton = tk.Radiobutton(self, image=self.wholeMilkImage,variable=m, value="Whole")
```

Comment: There's isn't enough code in your question to answer it and several of the functions look like they're written incorrectly. Please [edit] your question and add the missing code.

Comment: I don't understand how you keep order and how you write it in database.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. You've got too much code that seems irrelevant (none of the images seem necessary _to reproduce the problem_), and not enough code to run.